# How to copy files from a remote server that uses basic authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest

This may seem like a simple question but I'm writing a console application that needs to access files on a remote server. 
I've got a URL, a U/N and a P/W. The URL protocol is https of course and I do not have the option of using ftp or sftp.
When I access the remote path with a browser, I am asked for a u/n and p/w so it appears to be basic file authentication.

I've searched for various methods and have found solutions like Impersonation but most involve authenticating over a local network or a Windows network.

Is there any way i can use `File.Exists` and `File.Copy` methods on a server with this type of authentication?

The path I have is in the following format..

https://domain.net/folder/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the `WebClient` class in the .NET framework.

Try the following:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    var localPath = @"c:\file.txt";
    var remotePath = "http://example.com/files/somefile.txt";

    client.DownloadFile(remotePath, localPath);
}
```

This will download the file from `http://example.com/files/somefile.txt` and save it to `c:\file.txt`.

Comment: +1. Beware of sites with bad auth implementation like mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829609/why-is-use-of-new-networkcredentialusername-password-not-working-for-basic?rq=1

Comment: @Mun I'll give that a try. My project requirements seemed fairly simple at first but then I realized I would need to somehow authenticate with the server. I've used an API called ChilKat for sftp and ftp but this will be a first for just basic authentication over https.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I appreciate the heads up. I'll see what happens with Mun's solution real quick.

Comment: @Mun This solution is exaclty what I was looking for. I'm not sure if I was using the correct search terms for a solution like this but again, most people where only interested in authenticating over a local network of some sort. I highly appreciate this.