# C# - Logging into this website?

Tags: c#, web-services, webforms

How can I make my C# app log in to a website that requires username/password authentication?  The page uses Apache Struts, if it matters.

Comment: Show us how your C# app is currently trying to connect to that website

Comment: What do you mean? I have no idea how to do this so I don't have any code atm.

Comment: We usually do not do your homework or project.

Comment: I'm in High School. I would love if it had any classes to do with coding but sadly my school is full of rednecks. So no, its not my homework. Why do you assume such?

Comment: @user377419, please elaborate on what you are trying to actually accomplish once you login.  Do you want to pull down a bunch of data (use HtmlAgilityPack).  Do you want to interact with a JS/AJAX heavy website with lots of dynamic content?  (use WatiN)   Do you want low-level access at the HTTP level so you have complete control?  (use HttpWebRequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send data to the web server to simulate a form submission.

There are a few questions that already address this:

[Fake a form submission with C# WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726710/fake-a-form-submission-with-c-webclient)

[How to submit http form using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273998/how-to-submit-http-form-using-c)

Hopefully now you have a more clear idea of what you are looking for.