# Open Url sending POST

Tags: .net, winforms

How to open an webbrowser and sending POST within .net 2

something like this html function.

```
<form action="http:www.url.com/get" method="post">
  <input name="tt_2a" >
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

I want something lik the html function i have mentioned above, open an url, post something and see the results in the opened page. I Dont need web respose. thank you

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Are you talking about webforms (client side or server side?), WPF or winforms?

Comment: I want to open Url sending post using a winforms.

Comment: Please tag your question with winforms in that case, so you get relevant answers and more people looking at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the POST behind-the-scenes (that is, without displaying a browser window/control), these links may help:

- [How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)
- [Full HTTP POST/WebRequest Example (C#) and CSV file](http://technet.rapaport.com/Info/LotUpload/SampleCode/Full_Example.aspx)
- [HTTP Post](http://en.csharp-online.net/HTTP_Post)

Answer (score 4):

You want to post a WebRequest like this:

```
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close ();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close ();
        dataStream.Close ();
        response.Close ();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) in your winforms application in order to work with web pages.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793755/how-to-fill-forms-and-submit-with-webclient-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726710/fake-a-form-submission-with-c-webclient) question for more information on using `WebClient` to post form data.